# Tengo un problema con mi JS cuando utilizo la funcion onkeydown me dice que es deprecate

Tags: javascript, html

mi problema radica en que quiero usar la funcion onkeydown pero me la marca como obsoleta me podrian decir como reemplazarla es que nose como podria solucionarlo ya que aun asi funciona el codigo pero que me diga que es obsoleto molesta bastante en el codigo y mas cuando lo ves en VS code donde te lo subraya en verdad agradeceria su respuesta gracias de antemano

```js
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 32) { // spacebar
                console.log("aprete la barra de espacio")
            }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>SPACE WAR</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body id="ocean">
    <div id="start">
    </div>

    <div id="game">
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yo veo el `Console Log` que has puesto. A ti te da error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes utilizar directamente [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event)

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 32) { // spacebar
        console.log("aprete la barra de espacio")
    }

});
```

```html
<div id="start">
</div>

<div id="game">
</div>
```